# express middleware functions invoked twice when request is made from browser

Tags: node.js, express

Below is my nodejs code

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("In interceptor");
    next();
});

app.use('/users', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In /users middleware');
    res.send('<h1>From "/users" handler </h1>');
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Default handler");
    res.send('<h1>From default handler</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Console output when a request is made from browser (both chrome and edge)

```
http://localhost:3000
******************
In interceptor
Default handler
In interceptor
Default handler
******************

http://localhost:3000/users
******************
In interceptor
In /users middleware
In interceptor
Default handler
******************
```

But when a request is made using `curl`, I don't see multiple invocations

```
curl http://localhost:3000
******************
In interceptor
Default handler
******************

curl http://localhost:3000/users
******************
In interceptor
In /users middleware
******************
```

Can someone explain why middleware functions are invoked multiple times when request is made from browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual reasons you see multiple requests when a page loads from a browser are one of two things:

1. The browser automatically requesting the favicon.ico file.
2. The browser attempting to load some resource from the HTML file (script file, image, CSS file, etc..)

You can see exactly what each request is for by adding:

```
console.log(req.url);
```

to your middleware.

Comment: Thank you for the response. After posting the question, I did the same and found that duplicate invocation is caused by 'favicon.ico' request made by browser.

Answer (score 2):

Found that it is happening due to `/favicon.ico` request made by browser. Adding specific handler (shown below) prevented default handler from being called twice

```
app.use('/favicon.ico', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('favicon handler');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```